# How do I link an Excel cell to a PowerPoint textbox so that the linked information uses the PowerPoint formatting but the Excel data value?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I linked Excel data to a ppt deck and I want to edit the format of that linked data in the ppt, while keeping the data from the Excel cell and not altering the formatting of the Excel cell itself.

**I linked an Excel cell to a PowerPoint deck using:**

1. Ctrl+c+cell
2. Make text box in PPT
3. Paste special
4. Select paste link, select Microsoft excel worksheet object. This creates an image of the cell linked from Excel in the ppt.

**Current Result:**

In Excel: C2 = 800, is blue, with border, Calibri font

In PPT, after I linked to C2 to a textbox, I that textbox has the same value of 800, is blue, with border, Calibri font

**Desired Result:**

In Excel: C2 = 800, is blue, with border, Calibri font

In PPT, after I linked to C2 to a textbox, I want that textbox to have the same value of 800, be green, without border, Time New Roman font

I am open to all solutions ranging from clicking buttons to making a macro in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most time-efficient method is to format the Excel sheet to look like the result you want in PowerPoint. Excel links in PowerPoint are OLE objects, which visually reproduces the original Excel file.

The alternative would be to write a macro to copy and paste data to the presentation, then reformat it. This would not be a link. You would have to remember to re-run the macro every time you updated the Excel data.